# SwiftUI, tvOS - .onChange issue for focus and slow vertical scrolling

Tags: swiftui, tvos

I am having an issue when using .onChange() within my app.

I have 2 columns in a HStack.  Column 1 is a scrollview with Live TV Channels and Column 2 is the EPG information for this channel.  When the user scrolls through the live tv channels, the EPG info should update.

I can get this part working, but the vertical scrolling is laggy.  It's worse on the original Apple TV 4K model.

I have narrowed the issue down to the .onChange() lines.  If I remove these lines, the scrolling is super smooth.  Is there another way I can do this without using onChange maybe?

Here is some demo code to show the issue

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    enum Focusable: Hashable {
      case none
      case row(id: Int)
    }

    @FocusState var isFocused: Focusable?
    @State private var myText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            // first column
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(1..<500) { i in
                        Button {
                            //
                        } label: {
                            Text("Row \(i))")
                        }
                        .focused($isFocused, equals: .row(id: i))
                        .onChange(of: isFocused) { focus in
                            if focus == .row(id: i) {
                                myText = "Row \(i) focused"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // second column
            Text(myText)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```